# Add password at input without selectors jquery

Tags: jquery, input, passwords

I was trying to add the password into an input without class or id.

This is my code:

```
<form>
  <div class="something"> </div>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Watch Video">
</form>
```

And i was trying something like this:

```
jQuery(document.ready(function($){
   $('.something').next().write('password'); 
});
```

How can i make it?
And after put the password, can i submit the next input?

Comment: Tiny point but in this case I'd suggest `div#something` would be more appropriate than `div.something`, as I'd infer you want to refer to this single, unique element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the value of an input field you need to pass your string to the value property.

```
$('.something').next().prop('value', 'password');
```

Or you can use the shorthand `val()` method that populates the value property:

```
$('.something').next().val('password');
```

**I would also recommend not using the `next` function because this means you are 100% dependent on the ordering of the HTML elements.** I would suggest using a selector like this:

```
$('.something').siblings('input:password').val('password');
```

This selector will always work as long as the password field is in the same hierarchy as the `.something` element.

Reference - https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: Well explained , thanks for the tip about depend on the order of HTML, but in this case, the order will be the same 100%, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You set the value of `input` elements with `val`, not `write` (there is no jQuery `write` function). Other than that, your code is correct:

```
jQuery(document.ready(function($){
   $('.something').next().val('password'); 
   // --------------------^
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **val()** instead of write.

```
 $('.something').next().val('password');
```

The val() method returns or sets the value attribute of the selected elements.

When used to return value: 
This method returns the value of the value attribute of the FIRST matched element.

When used to set value: 
This method sets the value of the value attribute for ALL matched elements.

Note: The val() method is mostly used with HTML form elements.